# install Julia in anaconda

Tags: terminal, anaconda, julia

I wanna install Julia in my anaconda environment.
I tried install Julia by "conda install -c conda-forge julia"
but error is occurred

I already have conda-forge channel but can't install Julia, how do I fix it?

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- julia

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: Afaik it is not recommended to install Julia inside Conda, they do not play well together. Julia has its own system for package and environment handling. You can install directly from binaries on the website, or via juliaup

Answer (score 4):

According to the channels you listed (https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64), you are attempting to install Julia on macOS with an ARM architecture (e.g., M-series CPUs).

As of writing this answer, there is **no Julia package on conda built for ARM**, so you will be unable to install Julia with this package manager. You will have to use other package managers or install it manually (I recommend https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup).

See the following GitHub pull request for updates on the availability of Julia for ARM via conda-forge: https://github.com/conda-forge/julia-feedstock/pull/224. Once this pull request is merged, you can re-run the `conda install -c conda-forge julia` on your M-series Mac and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new environment using:

```
conda create -n juliaenv
```

and then activate the enviornment:

```
conda activate juliaenv
```

Then install Julia using into this environment using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge julia
```

If this reports `PackageNotFoundError` then head over to: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia and check if it lists the platform you are on. Currently it shows only Linux and Intel Macs.

In this case you can try another route by installing a Julia version manager.

```
conda install -c conda-forge juliaup
```

The type in

```
juliaup list
```

To see which versions are available. Install the version appropriate for your platform using:

```
juliaup add <version>
```

To install the version pinned as default/release, use:

```
juliaup add release
```

(To see a full list of commands check out: https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup)

At this point you will still need to tell your system where to find the Julia executable just installed. The command

```
juliaup config channelsymlinks true
```

will create a separate symlink to each version installed.

For example:

```
…/testfolder/ via ஃ 1.8.5 via  juliaenv [I]➜ juliaup config channelsymlinks true
Creating symlink julia-release for Julia 1.8.5+0.aarch64.apple.darwin14.
Symlink julia-release added in /Users/username/opt/miniconda3/envs/juliaenv/bin/julia-release. Add this directory to the system PATH to make the command available in your shell.
```